# Forward video stream to PC via USB-tethering

Tags: usb-tethering, video-streaming, vlc, scrcpy

On my Android phone, I run AirReceiver which mirrors the screen of  my iPad connected to it via mobile hotspot. In the app, I can choose the player (VLC, the default player, etc.) to play this video stream in. I would like to redirect this video stream from the phone to my Linux PC via USB-tethering. Is there a way to achieve it?

My current solution is to mirror the phone's screen with the video running in the foreground via scrcpy. However, the iPad's and the phone's screen have different dimensions, the resolution is lost and the video has to be cropped on the PC.

I was thinking of using VLC direct somehow but I don't know how.
Thanks for any tips!